# Mixpanel cookie not being set

Tags: mixpanel

TL;DR; Mixpanel doesn't set its cookie provoking the distinct_id to change constantly

I have 3 mixpanel projects: local/staging/pro. In local mixpanel tracking is working just fine, but in staging even with the code being identical (except the mixpanel token), events are being sent properly, but always with a disting_id changed. So, I see every event in mixpanel as if it were coming from a different device?!

I checked it and the problem is probably coming from the fact that mixpanel is not setting its cookie at all in my browsers.

The source code for staging looks like this:

```
<head>
    ...
    <script type="text/javascript" async="" src="//cdn.mxpnl.com/libs/mixpanel-2-latest.min.js"></script>
```

before

```
<script>
  (function(e,b){if(!b.__SV){var a,f,i,g;window.mixpanel=b;b._i=[];b.init=function(a,e,d){function f(b,h){var a=h.split(".");2==a.length&&(b=b[a[0]],h=a[1]);b[h]=function(){b.push([h].concat(Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments,0)))}}var c=b;"undefined"!==typeof d?c=b[d]=[]:d="mixpanel";c.people=c.people||[];c.toString=function(b){var a="mixpanel";"mixpanel"!==d&&(a+="."+d);b||(a+=" (stub)");return a};c.people.toString=function(){return c.toString(1)+".people (stub)"};i="disable time_event track track_pageview track_links track_forms register register_once alias unregister identify name_tag set_config people.set people.set_once people.increment people.append people.union people.track_charge people.clear_charges people.delete_user".split(" ");
  for(g=0;g<i.length;g++)f(c,i[g]);b._i.push([a,e,d])};b.__SV=1.2;a=e.createElement("script");a.type="text/javascript";a.async=!0;a.src="undefined"!==typeof MIXPANEL_CUSTOM_LIB_URL?MIXPANEL_CUSTOM_LIB_URL:"file:"===e.location.protocol&&"//cdn.mxpnl.com/libs/mixpanel-2-latest.min.js".match(/^\/\//)?"https://cdn.mxpnl.com/libs/mixpanel-2-latest.min.js":"//cdn.mxpnl.com/libs/mixpanel-2-latest.min.js";f=e.getElementsByTagName("script")[0];f.parentNode.insertBefore(a,f)}})(document,window.mixpanel||[]);
  mixpanel.init("xxxxxx3ecxxx68a2ff74xxxx", {debug:true});
</script>
```

and finally I track

```
<script>
  mixpanel.track('Visit');
</script>
```

Comment: Did you find any sort of solution here?

Answer (score 4):

If it is your staging site, you might be using a top level domain that don't allow cross subdomain cookies (think heroku, aws, etc), for example, yoursubdomain.herokuapp.com. You can either:

1. Map your staging yousubdomain.topleveldomain.com to staging.yourdomain.com using a CNAME record in your DNS settings

or

2. Manually enable cookies in mixpanel.init

   mixpanel.init(PROJECT_TOKEN, {cross_subdomain_cookie : false﻿})﻿;

Here is the mixpanel doc that explains: https://mixpanel.com/help/questions/articles/mixpanel-and-herokuappcom-subdomains-and-other-common-top-level-domains

And here is the list of top level urls that breaks cookies: https://publicsuffix.org/list/effective_tld_names.dat

Comment: Was about to have a mind explosion digging into why mixpanel was changing my distinct_id after sign_up after I found this... I was using ngrok which falls under the top level urls that breaks cookies. Thank you so much